# jQuery button click not triggered, after switching from one page to another using $location.apply() in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, buttonclick

We are working on building an angular js app.

We have button click event(jQuery) in first page.

The second page submission passes data to first page. we have used $location.path() to switch from second page to first page, post switching, button click(which is in first page) is not triggered.

Note : The button click works fine when the second page is not visited.

Code:

```
first page html :
<a id="buttonid" onclick="this.blur();" class="btn btn-warning btn-regular pull-right"
                    href="#/{{next.id}}">Next: {{next.name}} &raquo;</a>

first.js:

$("#buttonid").click(function(event)
{
//some stuff
});
second page.html
<a class="btn btn-warning btn-regular ng-binding ng-scope" ng-click="sendtofirst()" ng-disabled="isDisable">Post</a>

second.js

$scope.sendtofirst = function() {
$location.path('/firstpage');
};
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the code in question.

Comment: Why using a button with the click event made in jquery when you can easily use the button's onclick event?

Or in this case: <button ng-click="function()"></button>

Comment: We will need some code to help you out with this.

Comment: I have updated with code snippet. Could you please check.